# Azure data factory get object properties from array

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Get Metadata activity which get all child items under a blob container. There are both files and folders but i just need files. So in a filter activity which filter for only items of type = file. This is what I got from the filter activity:

```
    Output
    {
        "ItemsCount": 4,
        "FilteredItemsCount": 3,
        "Value": [
            {
                "name": "BRAND MAPPING.csv",
                "type": "File"
            },
            {
                "name": "ChinaBIHRA.csv",
                "type": "File"
            },
            {
                "name": "ChinaBIHRA.csv_20201021121500",
                "type": "File"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So there is an array of 3 objects being returned. Each object has a name and type properties. I want just the names to be fed to a store procedure activity as a parameter. I have used this expression to try to get a comma separated list as the parameter.

```
    @join(activity('Filter1').output.Value.name, ',')
```

and got this error:

```
            The expression 'join(activity('Filter1').output.Value.name, ',')' cannot be evaluated because property 'name' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.
```

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create For Each activity after Filter activity. Within For Each activity, append file name.

Step:

1.create two variable.
[image]

2.Setting of For Each activity
[image]

3.Setting of Append Variable activity within For Each activity
[image]

4.Setting of Set variable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below codeblock instead

```
@concat('''',join(json(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(
activity('Filter1').output.Value)
            ,',"type":"File"','')
        ,'"name":','')
    ,'{','')
,'}','')),''','''),'''')
```

This would forego the use of multiple activities, and you can use the existing framework that you have.